# Cannot insert data in firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to android development, I can read data from firebase DB but I can't insert new data into my firebase DB. I have also checked the firebase rules.  I have added dependencies properly. which is   `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.1.0'`, please let me know where I am wrong, I have checked many examples but do not know why my code is not working

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;

public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {

        private FirebaseDatabase fbase;
        private DatabaseReference mref;
        private Button registerbtn;
        private EditText emailtext;
        private EditText password;
        private EditText cpassword;

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Sign Up");
        fbase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
         mref = fbase.getReference(path: "users");

            emailtext =  findViewById(R.id.email);
            password  =  findViewById(R.id.password);
            cpassword =    findViewById(R.id.cpassword);
            registerbtn = findViewById(R.id.button);
            registerbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                RegisterUser();
          }
          });



    }

    private void RegisterUser()
     {

    String emailid = emailtext.getText().toString();
        String Password = password.getText().toString();
        String CPass    = cpassword.getText().toString();
        String Keys =  mref.push().getKey();

        mref.child(Keys).child("emailid").setValue(emailid);
        mref.child(Keys).child("password").setValue(Password);
 }
```

Comment: What is happening when you are using this code?

Comment: Please put the log.

Answer (score 1):

Actually your firebase DB might be expecting and object of User class, having the properties (emailId,password,confirmPassword). But what you are trying to do is just inserting each string as a User object, which will not work. You should try doing :

```
String tableName = "whatever table name you are using"; //probably users
User user = new User();
user.setEmail(emailid);
user.setPassword(Password);
user.setConfirmPassword(CPass);
mref.child(tableName).child(Keys).setValue(user);
```

And why are you passing a path parameter in getReference() method?

Comment: @farhanahmed also have a look at this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)

Answer (score 0):

```
I have tried this but result is same 

  public class users {
  private String nKeys, nemail, npass;

  users(){}
  users (String key , String email, String pass){

  this.nKeys = key;
  this.nemail = email;
  this.npass = pass;

 }

  public String getId() { return nKeys;}
  public String getEmail() { return nemail;}
  public String getpass() { return npass;}
  }

    ///////////

  fbase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();   
  mref = fbase.getReference();

  String tablename= "users";

  String emailid = emailtext.getText().toString();
  String Password = password.getText().toString();
  String CPass    = cpassword.getText().toString();
  String Keys =  mref.push().getKey();
  users user1 = new users(Keys , emailid, Password );

  mref.child(tablename).child(Keys).setValue(user1);
```